# PIC ADC Protection

Tags: pic, diodes, adc, offset

I am working on a project that samples a 1 kHz signal @ 20 kHz, the signal is 5Vpp biased on +2.5V that way everything is fine.

I want to make a protection schematics to work along my offset. I am reading several posts but nothing is clear to me. The offset circuit is just a voltage divider + LM2902 opamp as a buffer. I have read on the OPAMP datasheet that the input can go as far as +32V with +5V supply (excellent) and can be driven negative without damage but with a input current of 50mA, so is it okay to leave the OPAMP unprotected? There's no risk of static electricity or 230V AC touching my input.

If I put some clamping diodes these will be parallel to my voltage divider,  so at this moment I am a little confused of how to assemble. Can you give some ideas?

This is what i managed to design. What do you think?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Hi! It would help to specify against what dangers you'd like to protect your device. Will it be handled manually? (risk of static electricity shock) Is there a danger of 230V AC touching your input? Or do you just want to do it the "proper" way?
Also, your input signal covers the full range of the ADC. You may easily get some clipping, i.e. distortion on your digitized signal. Adding some head room could be wise. If relevant, tell us more about your signal?

Comment: @akwky there's no risk of static electricity or 230V AC touching my input. This is what i managed to design, what do you think? https://imgur.com/2OPZ7MG

Comment: what is it *actually* connected to? an external jack socket? another internal signal?